# Поиск js элемента по HTML коду

Tags: javascript, jquery, поиск

Возникла необходимость находить элементы по коду самих элементов, пример -

```
<a><img src="/bitrix/templates/mobile/images/google-play-img.png" alt="">test</a>
```

Не смог найти ничего подобного.

Comment: непонятна суть вопроса

Comment: ну так взять все элементы и найти тот у которого свойство `src` равно `/bitrix/templates/mobile/images/google-play-img.png`

Comment: Что непонятно? нужно найти по строке dom element и не по src и не по alt а по целой строке со всеми атрибутами которые могут появится в ней, или же могут появиться вложенные элементы, что тоже подразумевает поиск по строке.

Comment: Я думаю не целесообразно перебирать все параметры всех элементов html для того что бы находить разные сочетания свойств.

Comment: В общем нужен метод или функция которая может находить dom-element по строке из его HTML кода.

Comment: `<a><img src="/bitrix/templates/mobile/images/google-play-img.png" alt="">test</a>` и `<a><img alt="" src="/bitrix/templates/mobile/images/google-play-img.png">test</a>` - это разные элементы или одинаковые по твоим правилам? Откуда ты будешь получать строку, которую будешь искать?

Comment: У меня есть большая бд с кодами элементов, на которые будет вешаться js функция.

Comment: Берете первую точку отчёта, считываете innerHTML и там копаетесь - на здоровье. Например `document.body.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

Ну это просто. Тебе сначала надо распарсить данную строку. Так ты получишь список нод и их параметров. И тебе останется пробежаться по всем элементам документа и сравнить соответствие параметров и потомков.

Парсинг можешь заменить на создание элемента с данной html структурой. И сравнивать все ноды документа с нодами этого элемента.

Comment: Получается нужно будет все уровни вложенностей пройти за цикл на странице? а нет какого то поиска?

Comment: Ты можешь попробовать взять document.innerHTML, это весь html документа в строке. И искать строку в строке, получишь начальную позицию, далее можешь удалить эту часть строки.

Comment: Думаю это оптимальный алгоритм по скорости работы, хотя минусом является сложность реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так.
Ищем первый тег в строке поиска, в примере выше это `a`.

Далее через `document.getElementsByTagName` берём все теги `a` из документа, и сравниваем с поисковой строчкой через outerHTML.

**Обновлено:**
Сначала вставляем поисковый текст на страницу (куда-то в скрытое место, после работы поиска незабываем удалить элемент) и берём от него outerHTML, а потом делаем что я написал выше.
Зачем это надо? Дело в том что браузер хранит страницу в своём формате, и если у вас например лишний пробел есть, или перенос строки то алгоритм выше не сработает. Даже если в исходном файле где-то два пробела, то внутри браузера пробел будет один. Поэтому этим действием мы приводим строчку к браузерному виду, если в этом есть потребность.

Comment: То что ты видишь один пробел, это не значит что он там один. И документе их столько, сколько было изначально, никуда они не пропадают. А то что ты видишь только один, это лишь особенность рендера браузера. CSS свойство white-space: pre, покажет все пробелы.

Comment: @Profesor08 проверил на конкретном файле, действительно в строке между тегами пробелы и переносы строк сохраняются, а вот в атрибутной части тега, лишние пробелы а также переносы на другую строку удаляются, по-крайней мере в хроме.

Comment: @Profesor08 вот тест - https://jsfiddle.net/0qnt6kpt/

Comment: @Profesor08 более того он даже теги преобразоввывать может, в примере выше тег `<br/>` он преобразует в `<br>`

Comment: Ну так атрибуты для того и придуманы, чтоб не влиять на контент. А тегу <br> не требуется закрывающий тег.